# how to not forget to delete debug lines in code

Tags: debugging, bash, shell, workflow, zsh

This seems to me to be a novel idea (since i haven't found any solutions or anyone having implemented it)...

> A shell script that automatically runs whenever you git commit or whatever that will let you know if you forgot to delete any debugging or development env specific lines of code in your project.

For example:

Often times (in my Ruby projects) I'll leave lines of code to output variables like

```
puts params.inspect
```

or

```
raise params.inspect
```

Also, sometimes I'll use different methods so I can easily see the effects such as in cases like using delayed_job where I'd rather call the method without a delay during development.

The problem is sometimes I forget to change those methods back or forget to delete a call to raise params.inspect and I'll inadvertently push that code.

So I thought maybe the simplest solution was to add a comment to any such debugging line such as

```
raise params.inspect #debug
```

In essence flagging that line as a development only/debug line. Then in a shell script that runs before some other command like git commit it can use awk or grep to search through all the latest modified files for that #debug comment and stop execution and alert you. However i don't know much about shell scripting so I thought I'd ask for help :)

Comment: You don't need to write the script in a shell scripting language, you can write it using ruby if you want to.

Comment: In Java, it is a good practise to add if(log.isDebugEnabled) { debug logging..} I am not sure if something like that is present in shell.

Comment: @srikanthradix - The logback framework builds that check into itself so that you can just use `log.debug()` instead of cluttering up the code even more with `if` statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although I whole-heartedly recommend following cdeszaq'a advice and discourage doing this sort of thing, it is pretty easy to write a git hook that will prevent you from committing any lines with a particular string.  For simplicity, I'm not showing the git rev-parse --verify HEAD that you should use to make this hook work on an initial commit, but if you simply put the following in .git/hooks/pre-commit (and make it executable), you will not be able to commit any lines of code that contain the string '#debug':

```
#!/bin/sh

if git diff-index -p -M --cached HEAD | grep '#debug' > /dev/null; then
  echo 'debug lines found in commit.  Aborting' >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than having to remember to do additional work (removing lines of code) only to have to do *more* work later when things break again (re-adding that code), why not put in sensible debugging statements *from the beginning*?

Most languages have fairly expressive and often cheap logging libraries that will allow you to write out various levels of information (error, info, debug, trace) to a number of different locations (a file, a database). Many of these libraries will even let you adjust the logging level for a specific chunk of the code *at runtime* or even *while the program is running*.

So, rather than try to bandage up brute-force debugging by scripting away the problem, why not do yourself, and the rest of the world that has to use what you produce, a favor and use an actual logging framework for logging?

Comment: thanks for the answer but that does not solve the problem of using delayed_job or not depending on which environment you're in. I agree with you on the logging part of it though. I will put statements like that in their proper logger methods.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, you can use any programming language you feel comfortable with.

Anyway, searching for other commit hooks, I think [this one](https://github.com/niden/Git-Pre-Commit-Hook-for-certain-words/blob/master/pre-commit) could be a good one to start with. It basically looks for some words in your files and can be customized just changing the `checks` array in the top of the file.

Comment: This also solves the problem, just gave the answer to Pursell because it was similar and sooner :P Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@cdeszaq is correct about the logging part.

For *behaviour* that differs depending on environment, the common way to achieve this is to make the behaviour configurable. `delayed_job` should read a value from the config file to decide how long to delay. For production environments the config would have one value and for development environments the config would have a different value.